# Securing multiple microservices with JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I've a microservices structure for my current application. I also added an Auth-service that can provide a `JWT`. So far so good, but now I'm wondering how I can validate the token on other services?

I can validate the JWT by setting the secret to every service... but that doesn't seems very secure, right? (if one gets compromised, all are compromised)

I can't find an example (preferable ASP.Net core 3.1) where a JWT structure is built with two or more services.

Comment: in such scenarios you should work with asymmetric algorithms, eg. RS256 instead of the symmetric HS256. The auth service then signs, using the private key and all resource services can verify the token using the public key.

Comment: You could use Consul-Connect to do all of this for you using certs, or in conjunction with Vault to use JWT. Either way, what you're trying to do is really hard to get right, and most tutorials/guides only cover the trivial case which, as you've said, isn't really very secure.